# Passport.js local strategy how to secure route

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, passport.js

Apologies it's written in coffeescript (not pure js).
I've been looking at passport.js and am trying to include it into a project, here's a cut-down version of it with just the auth stuff.

```
express = require 'express'
passport = require 'passport'
LocalStrategy = require 'passport-local'
.Strategy
BasicStrategy = require 'passport-http'

app = express()
server = require 'http'
.createServer app
server.listen 3000

app.use express.cookieParser()
app.use express.session
  secret: 'abc'
app.use express.json()
app.use express.urlencoded()
app.set 'views', "#{__dirname}/views"
app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
app.locals.pretty = true
app.use passport.initialize()
app.use passport.session()

passport.use new LocalStrategy (username, password, done) ->
  if username is 'admin' and password is 'password'
    return done null, user =
      username: 'admin'
  else
    return done null, false, message: 'Incorrect username / password'

passport.serializeUser (user, done) ->
  done null, user.username

passport.deserializeUser (username, done) ->
  done null, user =
    username: username

app.get '/login', (req, res) ->
  res.render 'login',
    title: 'Login'

app.post '/login', passport.authenticate 'local',
  successRedirect: '/admin'
  failureRedirect: '/login'

app.get '/admin', (req, res) ->
  res.render 'admin',
    title: 'Admin'

app.get '/devices', (req, res) ->
  res.render 'devices',
    title: 'Devices'
```

It's very basic, in that the local strategy just checks that the username is 'admin' and password is 'password' but I'm not sure how to secure the '/admin' and '/devices' routes? I tried this sort of thing:

```
app.get '/devices', passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}, (req, res) ->
  res.render 'devices',
    title: 'Devices'
```

But this didn't seem to work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If users are successfully authenticated after login, you could do something like:

```
ensureAuthenticated = (req, res, next) ->
  if req.isAuthenticated() then return next() else res.send 401

app.get "/devices", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) ->
  res.render 'devices',
  title: 'Devices'
```

Answer (score 1):

`res.send(401)` is now deprecated.

You can also use ES6 syntax:

```js
const ensureAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => req.isAuthenticated() ? next() : res.sendStatus(401);
app.get('/devices', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => { ... })
```